# Icon button show text at initial rendering before loading - google fonts

Tags: css, frontend, google-font-api

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />

<span class="material-symbols-outlined">
delete
</span>
```

[image]

Initial phase its showing raw text and then after some time its display the icon, How can we fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set `display` in the params, which does the same thing as CSS `font-display` property does.

[Read more here.](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#use_font-display)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200&display=block" />

<span class="material-symbols-outlined">
delete
</span>
```